# Max post array size in asp.net MVC?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, post, binding

I have a binding problem in asp.net MVC.

I want to post 2 arrays to an action.

The problem is that when my first array is more than 1000 elements the other one is refuses to.

Does anyone know why? And how can I correct this?

Here is the data I post to mvc action :

```
EPFPSelectionsSites[0].UrlSite www.monsite1.com
EPFPSelectionsSites[1].UrlSite www.monsite2.com
EPFPSelectionsSites[2].UrlSite www.monsite3.com
EPFPSelectionsSites[3].UrlSite www.monsite4.com

EPFPValeursSelectionSeries[0].NomSerie 1a3
EPFPValeursSelectionSeries[0].Valeur 5
EPFPValeursSelectionSeries[0].Valeur 6
EPFPValeursSelectionSeries[1].NomSerie 6a5
EPFPValeursSelectionSeries[1].Valeur 7
EPFPValeursSelectionSeries[1].Valeur 3
```

So when EPFPSelectionsSites is more than 1000 elements, EPFPSelectionsSites is limited and EPFPValeursSelectionSeries is not bind.But it work with less elements.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show your code? How are you sending those arrays from the client and how your controller action looks like?

Comment: My guess is it's a `'GET'` request and the array is blowing the max URL length of your web server or browser

Comment: Darin I edited the question. Andras, it's not GET request. I use jQuery $.post method.

Comment: Could you show this $.post method? Also could you show your controller action signature and the objects involved there?

Comment: @Dragouf - make sure the `[HttpPost]` attribute is applied to the action method and try it - what happens?

Comment: I had [HttpPost] but it changed nothing.Here is the $.post method : $.post('EpGraphPositions', epFiltre, function (data) { /*draw chart with json data*/ }, 'json');

Comment: check you are not going over your maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength in your web.config (<system.web> <httpRuntime maxRequestLength/> and <system.webServer> <security>      <requestFiltering> <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength />)

Comment: in my web.config maxAllowedContentLength is set to 20971520 and maxRequestLength to 40960. My posted datas ar just array of urls with 1017 elements only. I don't think it's more than this size ?

Comment: it seems that my first array reach a limit at 996 elements.... Strange

Comment: Uhm... is there a reason you want to return so many items back?  From a UI design pov it's my understanding that it's generally considered bad practice to display more then 100 items to a user.  After that you want to incorporate searching/paging/etc.  Also from a data transfer pov 1000 items seems like a lot of data..

Comment: It's because I have an UI with lots of filter choice on the top and then I generate a chart depending on those filter choice. User have some filtered dropdown where he can add all those elements... So I think it's how I have to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had a similar issue in an older webforms app back in February. [See this post for more details](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/12/28/asp-net-security-update-shipping-thursday-dec-29th.aspx).

What we had to do was add this to our web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="3000"/>
```

After that, all of the HTTP collection keys that were needed by our page were successfully POSTed. Hopefully this security update is what is causing your issue, and overriding the new security setting using the appSetting will get you all of your array items posted.